# Update by id, return id's that don't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with products, they all have a unique ID.

```
ID | PRODUCT | PRICE | SKU
1  | Apple   | 10    | 1
2  | Banana  | 15    | 2
```

I would like to run an update for the prices based on the id, but the update list may contain products that are not in the database yet. So it needs to return the ones that it can't update or didn't update.

update list:

```
ID | PRODUCT   | PRICE | SKU
1  | Apple     | 15    | 1
3  | pineapple | 25    | 3
```

now I need it to update ID 1, price = 15 and return that ID 2 hasn't been updated and also that ID 3 doesn't exist

This is due to the following, the website sells tyres, every year there's an updated list with pricing, this is based on the product_sku (not product_id) but is unique either way. I need to update the prices for all the ones in the new list and have a returned list with ID's that are in the new list but not the old, so we can add those later and also have a list of id's in the database but not the new list so we may delete them later (based on current stock levels)

If seperated into multiple steps I would think something like this:

```
$updated_skus = array();
foreach ($update_products as $product) {
  UPDATE 'tyres' SET 'price' = '$product['price']' WHERE 'sku' = '$product['sku']';
  $updated_skus[] = $product['sku'];
}
$current_skus = SELECT 'sku' FROM 'tyres';
```

ok now this part is not in code but the idea is this, any sku not in current_skus and in updated_skus is a new possible product, vice versa is an old product. So I would need to get 2 lists returned, new products, old products.

Comment: And what is your question? Please post in the question, what code you already have

Comment: I would like to know how to do this.

Comment: My guess is that you want to return all ids that are not between MIN and MAX? Why would you want that? Doesn't make any sense :P

Comment: no that'd be easy. This is due to the following, the website sells tyres, every year there's an updated list with pricing, this is based on the  product_sku (not product_id) but is unique either way.
I need to update the prices for all the ones in the new list and have a returned list with ID's that are in the new list but not the old, so we can add those later and also have a list of id's in the database but not the new list so we may delete them later (based on current stock levels)

Comment: I guess that @Burrito want to update a certain product which ID is already existing in the database and return a sucess promt, and if that ID is not existing then the system should prompt the ID is not existing.

Comment: yes, what Aljie said!

Answer (score 1):

To get IDs that aren't updated:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN updates u ON p.id = u.id
WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

To get products that don't exist, reverse the join:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM updates u
LEFT JOIN products p ON u.id = p.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Comment: the update list is not a table, it's a data array. only the original product list is a table

Comment: Load it into a table. MySQL can't do anything with data arrays.

Comment: Alternatively, include a last_modified column.